# Solana. Need to export all addresses from the blockchain to the DB

Tags: blockchain, dump, solana

I found a way:
https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins OR
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres

But for this need to deploy the validator with very high requirements
https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs

Is it possible to find a dump such a DB?
Or can configure the validator with minimal settings only for create such a DB?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a low-spec validator (maybe even from your local machine) just to fetch a snapshot from the network, and once the ledger is populated, use `solana-ledger-tool` to export all addresses:

```
$ solana-ledger-tool accounts -l path/to/your/ledger --no-account-data
```

Here's some sample output:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111:
  - balance: 0.000000001 SOL
  - owner: 'NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111'
  - executable: true
  - slot: 0
  - rent_epoch: 0
  - data_len: 14
AddressLookupTab1e1111111111111111111111111:
  - balance: 0.000000001 SOL
  - owner: 'NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111'
  - executable: true
  - slot: 0
  - rent_epoch: 0
  - data_len: 28
BPFLoader1111111111111111111111111111111111:
  - balance: 0.000000001 SOL
  - owner: 'NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111'
  - executable: true
  - slot: 0
  - rent_epoch: 0
  - data_len: 36
```